# Filter out <td> from .GET DATA

Tags: jquery

How would I get all the td elements with `class="chats"` from the `data` variable returned in my .get()?

```
$.get(file.html, function(data) {
    var returnedChats = $("td.chats").find("td", data);
    $('#regions').html(returnedChats);
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `file.html` returns a valid HTML and `#regions` is a `tr` element, you can try:

```
$.get('file.html', function(data) {
    $(data).find("td.chats").appendTo('#regions');
}, 'html');
```

Comment: Thank you so much, how about all td's after the 3rd one? something with :eq children(3)?

Comment: You are welcome.     `$(data).find("td.chats").filter(':gt(2)').appendTo('#regions');`

Comment: Great! one last question: my html filtered is giving me `<td class="Chats">Item 1</td><td class="Chats"></td><td class="Chats"></td><td class="Chats"></td><td class="Chats"></td><td class="Chats">Item 2</td><td class="Chats"></td><td class="Chats"></td><td class="Chats"></td><td class="Chats"></td><td class="Chats">Item 3</td><td class="Chats"></td><td class="Chats"></td><td class="Chats"></td><td class="Chats"></td>` How would I just get the elements with text? or every 5th <td>?

Comment: @BarclayVision Please post another question for that. I can't provide useful information in the comments.

Comment: thanks, here is new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19079222/jquery-return-only-text-from-filtered-results