# jquery return only text from filtered results

Tags: jquery

my html filtered is giving me

```
$.get(myURL, function(data) {
            $(data).find("td.Chats").filter(':gt(5)').appendTo('#regions');
        }, 'html')
```

results:

```
<td class="Chats">Item 1</td>
<td class="Chats"></td>
<td class="Chats"></td>
<td class="Chats"></td>
<td class="Chats"></td>
<td class="Chats">Item 2</td>
<td class="Chats"></td>
<td class="Chats"></td>
<td class="Chats"></td>
<td class="Chats"></td>
<td class="Chats">Item 3</td>
<td class="Chats"></td>
<td class="Chats"></td>
<td class="Chats"></td>
<td class="Chats"></td>
```

How would I just get the elements with text? or every 5th ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.filter()` method:

```
$(data).find("td.Chats").filter(function(){
    return this.innerHTML !== '';
});
```

Or `.not()` method:

```
$(data).find("td.Chats").not(':empty');
```

If you want to exclude the first element:

```
$(data).find("td.Chats").not(':empty').not(':first');
```

Comment: thanks again, sorry to blast you with simple stuff, just on a time constraint to get a site back up with jquery I know very little about.